# Hibernate mapping to a class that extends an abstract

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a superclass for all my db objects.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DBObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

But sometimes i want to create a reference to another object by just using the superclass (i.e. FK through id)

```
@Entity
public class Person extends DBObject {

    private DBObject shirt;

}
```

This gives error: 'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Mapped Superclass'

Basically, the reason for this is, i can have tables for all different kinds of shirts and i would be able to assign whichever one of them to the person.

**How do i tell hibernate that i dont want to use the DBObject class itself, but a class that extends DBObject**

Comment: Worth to mention i've tried with: private Class<? extends DBObject> shirt; without much success ('One To One' attribute type should not be 'Class')

Comment: As your entities map a database relationship you at some point have to specify the concrete target entity. You could to that with a JPA annotation eg `@OneToOne(target = ConcreteEntity.class)`. But mapping to an abstract `MappedSuperclass` will never work. Think about how that is supposed to be modelled in the database. What foreign key could Hibernate use to map from the `Person` table to an uknown number of subclasses of `DBObject`?

Comment: That being said, you can reference to an abstract entity if you use actual Inheritance: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html - You just have to turn your abstract superclass in an actual entity and choose a fitting inheritance type (InheritanceType.JOINED would work).

Comment: I think u might be right. I was thinking that the Person table has to have a shirt_id that references the shirt. But what shirt table is that gonna be? Its not gonna be possible without a reference to the specific shirt table as well.

Comment: Guess in this case, i have to change my shirt from DBObject to Long, and have a String Type as well, and then handle it in the code. I was hoping hibernate could do this for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use following at abstract class:

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)